# LOCAL HTML file to generate a text file

Tags: html

I am trying to generate a TEXT/XML file from a **LOCAL HTML** file. I know there are a lot of answers to generating a file locally, usually suggesting using ActiveX object or HTML 5. 
I'm guessing there is a way to make it work on all browsers (in the end HTML extension is opened by a browser even if it is a LOCAL file) and easily since this is a LOCAL file put in by user himself.

My HTML file will be on client's local machine not accessed via HTTP.
It is basically just a form written in HTML that upon "SAVE" command should be generating an XML file in the local disk (anywhere user decides) and saving form's content in.

Any good way?

Comment: So let me get this straight: you're trying to first generate a HTML file, and then let the user download that file, after the user submits a form? If that's what you meant, it's entirely possible, but before I post an answer I'd like to verify that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for your time. No download. I will mail an HTML file, he will put on his desktop and open, fill the text fields on the form and hit save. Save will just take those fields and make it an XML file and again save on his local disk. That's all.

Comment: It seems you do not want to use any communication whit server. It suppose to just work as desktop application. If this is the case you should go for a desktop client application which client can directly from hi desktop. In other case you must have to get posted data back to your sever, process that and send back xml.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of is, the html form elements can be set into class variables and then using the jaxb context you can create an XML file out of it.

Useful Link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Comment: Thanks but this seems like will require JAXB libraries to be loaded on    users PC, that's not what we want to deal with.

Comment: It doesn't require anything to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [base64 data-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/1256925) (no support for IE9-) to download the file:

First you need to create a temporary iframe element for your file to download in:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

Then you need to define what you want the contents of the file to download to be, and convert it to a base64 data-url:

```
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Foo</title></head><body>Hello World</body></html>';
htmlurl = btoa(html);
```

and set it as source for the iframe

```
ifrm.src = 'data:text/x-html;base64,'+htmlurl;
```

Comment: Not sure how. Can you give a simple example. Please keep in mind that this code will be hosted in the HTML file I give to the user. So var "html = ... " line is confusing me since the HTML string will be the file itself.

Comment: This uses JavaScript. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Sure, but what should I get "var html = " equal to, file itself?

Comment: Yes, you put the contents of the html file in that var